# node can't run with babel

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was following this tutorial https://medium.com/@bneiluj/es6-with-babel-in-your-node-app-3f254f6aa65f to understand node running on babel. So I made everything the same but couldn't run babel since the following error came up after running `npm run prepublish`

```
> cabinet@1.0.0 prepublish 

/Users/.../PhpstormProjects/***/cabinet
> npm run compile


> cabinet@1.0.0 compile /Users/.../PhpstormProjects/***/cabinet
> babel — presets es2015 -d lib/ app/

— doesn't exist. presets doesn't exist. es2015 doesn't exist
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! cabinet@1.0.0 compile: `babel — presets es2015 -d lib/ app/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

but es2015 was installed and it clearly sees in the package.json

```
{
"name": "cabinet",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/run.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "babel — presets es2015 -d lib/ app/",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

my project structure looks like this

```
- cabinet/
    - app/
       - run.js
    - lib/ # compiled one from app/
    - node_modules/
    .babelrc
    .package.json
```

Comment: 'npm check-dependencies' may clarify your issue

Comment: Looks like you've borked a copy/paste. Should be `--presets es2015` not `— presets es2015`. And make sure you've actually installed the preset `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: @BenFortune after fixing those it compiled successfully